# Returning an Object from a Realm query throws instance closed state exception

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

I have a function that returns a realm object.

```
private fun getNext(): MyRealmObject? {
        var item: MyRealmObject? = null
        try {
            Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
                realm.executeTransaction { r: Realm ->
                    item = r.where(MyRealmObject::class.java).equalTo(MyRealmObject.PROPERTY_ID, 1).findFirst() ?: return@executeTransaction
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.localizedMessage!!)
        } finally {
            return item
        }
    }
```

However when I call the function and try to access the properties, I get the error:

> IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed,
> making it unusable.

```
private fun doSomething() {
    val item = getNext() ?: return
    val title = item.title // Error thrown here
}
```

What am I failing to do properly here?

---

MyRealmObject.kt

```
@RealmClass
open class RealmPhoto : RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Index
    lateinit var id: Int

    var title: String = ""


    companion object {
        const val PROPERTY_ID = "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your exception says Realm has been closed and you cannot access its properties.

using `FindFirst()` it returns a `managed` object back which needs realm to be open when you access it.

Your fix would be to use `copyFromRealm`

So change your query to the following

```kotlin
r.where(MyRealmObject::class.java).equalTo(MyRealmObject.PROPERTY_ID, 1).findFirst()?.copyFromRealm() ?: return@executeTransaction
```